# Manganese oxide reacts with tin(IV) hydroxide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals

I have a problem on my chemistry summer homework in which it asks me to predict the product of “solid Manganese-Oxide when it reacts with tin(IV)-hydroxide in aqueous solution”. My issue is that there are multiple manganese oxides (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manganese_oxide) And that, normally,  neither hydroxide nor tin are water soluble.  How do I solve this?  I am allowed to answer that there will be no reaction, but how do I prove this, and how am I sure?  This is for A.P. Chemistry summer homework.

Comment: You guessed it right, it is a vague question. You can mention it is neither can acid-base reaction nor a redox reaction.

Comment: You may have already constructed an answer, it does not react under ordinary conditions. Now, there may be an issue with the question where reagents required, reaction conditions,..., have been omitted, so qualify your answer.

Comment: @M.Farooq: Also I'm not sure $\ce{Sn(OH)4}$ exissts or not. I think OP should look into that too. Any suggestion?